# Why does omitting an argument to printf print garbage?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, printf

I am using printf via assembly code. I note that in the following example if I ommit the expected argument, garbage is printed.

```
    .386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
    .data
msg3fmt byte 0Ah,"%s",0Ah,"test output",0Ah,0
    .code
main proc
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg3fmt
    ret
main endp
    end
```

My question is why? Is there a set memory address printf uses expecting to find an argument? Why is anything printed at all since no argument is passed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the format specifiers tell printf how many arguments it should have received. Printf gets its data from the stack; if you don't provide any data for it then it will pull whatever happened to be on the stack and treat as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The Standard says

> If the number of format specifiers in `printf()` is greater than the number of arguments the behavior is undefined.

Undefined Behavior means **anything** can happen.

Comment: I was asking the why behind what happened, not a general answer that behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Sonny That's the thing about undefined behaviour. The 'why' is undefined. It is... Undefined behaviour. The behaviour you saw can have a likely cause "Argument not found on the stack", but on ARM the first few varargs arguments are in registers, so the answer would be wrong. You can dream up all sorts of valid schemes for varargs and C calling conventions. So the only clear, concise thing to say is that it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @James but I was asking why what happened did. There is a difference in saying many scenario are possible and explaining the cause for a specific scenario.